# Binomial distribution - Variance (Experimental vs theoretical)

Tags: distributions, variance, binomial-distribution

Just been experimenting with creating a simulation for the binomial distribution.

I've made an applet in Geogebra that generates the histogram, mean of the experimental data, the variance of the experimental data and an estimate of the population variance using (n-1)/n from the sample variance for any chosen n,p and number of trials to repeat the experiment.

When the experimental is compared to the theoretical the means agree closely, but the variance of the experimental data seems closer to the theoretical variance np(1-p).  (Not always but often).

What's the statistical background behind this?

[image: Example comparison of experimental to theoretical]

Here's a link to the applet, to see what I mean, https://www.geogebra.org/m/cnyecwsd

Additional information
Binnomial variance experiment
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dNOvmb-KfYS7Lz0VhKnR4gv8Aw1ZppRN

Comment: On average, this estimate of the variance *equals* the theoretical variance.  Why, then, should we be surprised that in simulations the estimate is close to the theoretical value?

Comment: The variance of the sample is closer to the theoretical variance then the estimate of the variance of the population based on the sample.  This is what confuses me.

Comment: Could you share with us the data and analysis you performed to arrive at that conclusion?  I'm not saying it's incorrect, but only trying better to understand what you are getting at.

Comment: I've fixed it now.  The issue was the computer was calculating the variance of the sample as if it were the population.